# How to insert space of length of 1/4 spacing?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, lengths

When preparing a paper, the editor asked me to replace the separator `,` in numbers like $150,627,005$ with a 1/4 spacing.

So how to insert space of length of 1/4 spacing?

Comment: Does `\hspace{0.25ex}` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using of the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{150 627 005}% the same result get \num{150627005}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it should be clarified that you don't have to input the spaces yourself. writing `\num{150627005}` does the trick as well.

Comment: @schtandard, you are right. I will add comment to answer.